# When to put dollar sign $ at the reference to symbol in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, dollar-sign

I have both books by T.Parr about ANTLR and I see dollar sign all over with references to symbols. It work(ed) for me too:

```
term : IDENT -> { new TokenNode($IDENT) };
```

or something more complex:

```
type_enum : 'enum' name=IDENT '=' val+=IDENT (',' val+=IDENT)* ';' 
            -> { new EnumNode($name,$val) };
```

But this line gives me absurd error:

```
not_expr :  term 
         | NOT ex=not_expr -> { new UnaryExpression($NOT,$ex) };
```

The error says `missing attribute access on rule scope: ex`. You know what the fix is? Removing the dollar sign on "ex". That's it.

Out of curiosity I checked the mentioned rules (above) and removed the dollar sign -- they work as before (i.e. I don't get any error).

**QUESTION**: so what is this story with dollar sign? Should I not use it? Or should I use it until I get an error?

*I would not ask this question, if I not saw this convention almost used as a standard in ANTLR.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> QUESTION: so what is this story with dollar sign? Should I not use it? Or should I use it until I get an error?

It depends what you want to reference.

Understand that there are 3 different types of "labels":

1. `name=IDENT`, the label `name` references a `CommonToken`;
2. `val+=IDENT`, the label `val` references a `List` containing `CommonToken` instances, in this case;
3. `ex=not_expr` the label `ex` references a [`ParserRuleReturnScope`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/classorg_1_1antlr_1_1runtime_1_1_parser_rule_return_scope.html)

I recommend always using a `$`. I don't know if it is by design that `NOT ex=not_expr -> { new UnaryExpression($NOT,$ex) };` doesn't work, but to get a hold of whatever `not_expr` matched, I'd simply do this:

```
not_expr : term 
         | NOT ex=not_expr -> { new UnaryExpression($NOT, $ex.tree) }
         ;
```

I don't see why you'd want to get a hold of the entire `ParserRuleReturnScope`: the `tree` holds all the information you need.

HTH

Comment: Well, I don't want to do hold anything :-), I want to pass a tree to another tree constructor. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: I'm assuming the label `ex` in `ex=not_expr` is  a reference to `ParserRuleReturnScope` because it is a parse rule (while `IDENT` is a token)?